# Tablix pushing other elements down

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with a tablix in it. I just need to stay the tablix in a fixed position and shouldn't push down other elements down it. If say there are 4 rows which will be visible in the specified space and if more then it should not be visible and shouldn't push down other elements.
I tried several ways to prevent

1. Added tablix inside a rectangle(act as a container) so if it grouped it 
    will not push down other elements (didn't work)
2. Enable consume white space in report=true (didn't work)
3. Keep items together property is set to true in rectangle (didn't work)

Is there any other way to not to pushdown elements in the report even if the tablix gives more rows. It should only show the rows in the mentioned size.

Edit : 1 (7/28/2018)

[image]

All the three elements below is pushed down if the table has more rows.
Either I have to fit the rows in this table by reducing the size automatically if possible or It should not push down the elements.
Also if the tablix has less row the elements will move up. I just need to keep the elements (Expr) should stay in the same position.

Comment: Can you post your report design so we can take a look

Comment: @AlanSchofield, added image for your reference. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Please see the full answer below. If the answer below worked, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still didn't post your design but anyway, here is what I think you want.

The basic idea to to set the area you want you table to cover by using a rectangle of the same size. Then we will reduce the row heights within reason as the number of rows in the table increases. As you cannot directly change a row height, we can get round this by setting the row height to be very small and adjusting the font, as long as the can grow option is on the cells will grow to fit the font size, giving the effect of changing the row height.

Basic steps.

Create your report and add a rectangle that is the maximum size you want your table to be. In my example it's 38mm high.

Create a table inside the rectangle. I find this easier to create it outside then cut and paste it inside, simply dragging it over the rectangle will not work.

Position your additional text boxes, under the rectangle as desired. Set 'Consume Container WhiteSpace' on in the report properties.

Next we need to decide what the maximum and minimum font sizes are that acceptable. In this basic example I only use 3 sizes, 10pt, 12pt and 14pt. If you want to use more then you could write an expression to scale the fonts more accurately but you get the idea.

You'll need to determine the maximum number of rows you can fit into the rectangle when the minimum font size is used, in my case it's 5 rows at 10pt font. Your query will need to take this number into account and never return more rows than this.

On the table, the click row selector for the detail row (this basically selects all the cells in the row). Next, change the font size property to an expression. In this simple example I used this.

```
=SWITCH(
Parameters!topx.Value <3 , "14pt",
Parameters!topx.Value <5 , "12pt",
True, "10pt"
)
```

Next set the row height, choose any cell on the row and set the height to something small, I used 4mm but it doesn't matter as long as its' smaller then you will ever show.

In my example, for testing I added a 'topx' parameter and filtered the dataset using this, but this is only for testing.

The final design looked like this. I added a background colour to the rectangle so you can see how it remains static until it's filled.

[image]

Then running with various  rows looks like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

finally, only if I exceed my maximum (5 rows in this case) does the text below move down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your report to be that static, why not take a screenshot of the data and include that as an image in your report?

No serious reporting tool will "ignore" records that you pass to it using a Dataset, so that's the place where you will have to "ignore" all unwanted data yourself. Restrict the data in the Dataset to only 4 rows (maybe using `SELECT TOP 4 ...`).

Comment: is there any feature in SSRS that it will fit the data pre-defined size? if there more rows will it shrink automatically to fit in the size?

Comment: Please read my answer again, and if you still have no idea then read it again and again. The answer is "No, SSRS will not cut off everything bejond a size of 4 rows for you, you will have to cut the data off yourself!"

Comment: I understand the issue lies in if the tablix returns 1 row the element moved up so how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You could include a column (let's call it RowNumber) in your dataset that shows the row number of the data. Then in your Tablix filter, you can set the filter to show only values from that "RowNumber" column that are less than or equal to the number of rows you want to display in the tablix.

You can use the same concept to limit the number of rows returned in your query, but without knowing how you are getting the data, it is not possible to help with that.